# Java8 simplify expression using Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an code block:

```
public Builder withMultiValueMap(MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap) {
  ...
  withRespondentId(Long.valueOf(multiValueMap.getFirst("respondentId")));
  ...
  return this;
}
```

Sometimes map can return **null** if no value for *respondentId* key.
I can process it in old way using something like

```
  String respondentId = multiValueMap.getFirst("respondentId");
  withRespondentId(respondentId == null? null: Long.valueOf(respondentId));
```

...but I want do it better!

Is it possible simplify using **java8 Optional** or other stuff?

Comment: I don't know about better... `Optional.ofNullable(respondentId).map(Long::valueOf).orElse(null))`

Comment: Super. This is exactly i need! Thank you. please add an answer to mark it solved.

Comment: The code will be cleaner refactor such that the `withRespondentId` method doesn't require a `null` (maybe initialize with the `null` scenario set). You could then write `Optional.ofNullable(respondentId).map(Long::valueOf).ifPresent(this::withRespondentId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that has the same result as this expression:

```
respondentId == null? null: Long.valueOf(respondentId)
```

is

```
Optional.ofNullable(respondentId).map(Long::valueOf).orElse(‌​null)
```

Since it's actually longer, it's not a complete win, although it might pass as more readable.

Comment: Yeah, I'd very much prefer the first version.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If you have a nullable reference, I usually think it's a mistake to box it into an Optional for the purpose of calling Optional methods, only to unbox it immediately.

Comment: @StuartMarks yes?  We're in agreement here.

Answer (score 1):

If `MultiValueMap` is your own class, you can migrate `getFirst` to

```
Optional<V> getFirst(K key);

multiValueMap.getFirst(key).map(Long::valueOf).getOrElse(null);
```

Comment: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<K, V>